# Faster constant string appending without macro

Tags: c++

So when combining strings, oftentimes there are constant components, for example:

```
std::string s;
s += initial_string;
s += "const string";
s += terminating_string;
```

That's just a demonstration, string operations can be quite a bit more complex and in-depth.  So, when doing the const part, the implementation ends up "not knowing" the length and effectively does a `strlen()` on it.  Clearly this is a waste, as the length is known at compile time.  I've tested that replacing the const string part with this is quite a bit faster (substantially more in x64 for whatever reason):

```
s.append("const string",12);
```

It's annoying, time-consuming, and error-prone to actually count the characters, so this is a little better:

```
s.append("const string",sizeof("const string")-1);
```

That's still somewhat error prone (i.e. change the first part but forget to change the second part) so a macro can help this:

```
#define strnsizeof(s) s,sizeof(s)-1
s.append(strnsizeof("const string"));
```

**Question 1: Anybody have a better/cleaner solution to this?**

I've also got an extended string class where I use the `<<` operator for concatenating strings and various other object types.  Similar issue here, this is nice and clean (to me):

```
s << initial_string << "const string" << terminating_string;
```

When I have an operator for my own object type (of which length is a component) the append operation is fast and easy, but when it gets the `const char *` here again, I don't get the length even though it's constant at compile time.  So I can speed that up by creating a little structure that takes a `const char *` and length along the lines of:

```
s << initial_string
    << MyStr::ConstBuf(strnsizeof("const string"))
    << terminating_string;
```

Boy is that getting ugly.  So I could macro that out too, e.g.:

```
#define MyStrConst(s) MyStr::ConstBuf(s,sizeof(s)-1)
s << initial_string
    << MyStrConst("const string")
    << terminating_string;
```

Better but not great.

**Question 2: Anybody got a better/cleaner solution than encapsulating the constant string?**

Comment: A function that takes the character array by reference would do.

Comment: Is there something wrong with `std::stringstream`?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something in the character array comment... how would one get the length?  e.g. `void fn(char ar[])` I wouldn't have a compile-time length...

Comment: @dunc123 When trying to increase performance, everything is wrong with stringstream

Comment: Also make a variadic template function that appends multiple strings at once so it can `reserve()` once before everything.

Comment: @mark: `template<size_t SZ> void fn(char (&arr)[SZ]) { ... }` -- size can be accessed in the function via `SZ`, which is constant expression.  The function can be called as `fn("const string")` -- `SZ` will be automatically deduced.

Comment: ... are you very that desperate to make your program faster ? I mean, STL is designed for its ease of use, if you want speed, why don't you just use char* ?

Comment: @Uman: The STL is designed for ease of use, and for efficiency.  What's wrong with wanting both?

Comment: I take it you have profiled and that this is where all your performance is going?

Comment: "I've tested that replacing the const string part with this is quite a bit faster (substantially more in x64 for whatever reason)"

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: yes that does test out to near as I can tell the same as using append with sizeof, thanks!  I'm not sure the net "usability" is better than the macro but I'll play with it.  Also need to figure out how to integrate that somehow in my `<<` operator usage...

Comment: @BenHymers: Saying one method is faster than another is quite a bit different to saying 99.9% of my program's runtime is in adding constant strings together.

Comment: @graham.reeds His question was how to make the optimization simpler. If his app truly needs it or not is irrelevant to answering.

Comment: For what it's worth, yes, my application does a substantial amount of string manipulation... part of a multi-tenant hosted service that gets hammered with string-based requests and responses.

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: your template comment has let to a solution for both my questions and performs as well as expected.  If you care to take the time to put it in answer form I'll gladly accept, or just put a shell in place and I'll edit in what I came up with.  Or I'll edit my question.  Thanks again.

Comment: Feel free to add your own answer.  Don't add the answer to your question, put it as a post in the answer section.  I didn't answer because I didn't actually read the question.  I was just responding to your comment about R. Martinho Fernandes' original idea.  By the way, my original comment was wrong.  It was missing a const on the char, so make sure you add that, even if your compiler accepts it without the const.

Comment: Have you compared the performance if you call `std::string::reserve()` prior to starting the appends?  I would expect that it's possible the implementation would not have to expand the string as it's appending it.

Comment: Yes that's definitely an improvement as well, albeit a different one than saving the strlen.

Answer (score 3):

Comments to the question resulted in a template like the following:

```
template<size_t SZ> std::string& operator<<( std::string &s, const char(&arr)[SZ] ) {
    s.append( arr, SZ-1 );
    return s;
}
```

So instead of `s += "const string"` the template is utilized when doing:

```
s << "const string"
```

Additionally, I was able to update my extended string class such that the following utilizes a template to get the constant size as well:

```
s << initial_string << "const string" << terminating_string;
```

**EDIT: this does not work as expected:**

```
typedef struct { char buffer[32]; } ST;
ST st = { "1234" };
s << st.buffer;  // results in s with size 31!
```

This can be solved via a non-const template, e.g.:

```
template<size_t SZ> std::string& operator<<( std::string &s, char(&arr)[SZ] ) {
    s.append( arr ); // NOTE not using SZ here so a strlen happens
    return s;
}
```

So now:

```
s << st.buffer;  // results in s with size 4
```

Except:

```
const ST cst = &st;
s << cst.buffer;  // results in s with size 31 again...
```

Same issue when `buffer` is in a `class`, as you'd expect.

Comment: Just make sure that if you release this code for others to use, that you carefully document this behavior.  Since passing null terminated strings stored in char arrays that are longer than the string will not have the behavior that people expect.

Comment: Yes indeed, something I discovered when at first I didn't have the `-1` in the append.  Also the `const` part of the `arr` parameter was necessary...

Comment: More to your point, places I have an object member `char value[Max_Len+1]` so that `value` doesn't require additional heap allocation beyond the parent object now utilize the template and appends the entire `Max_Len` regardless of how much of the storage is being used.  I can resolve that by creating another template but without the `const` then using the `+= operator` which goes back to using the `strlen`.  Except when the object itself is const, then it's back to const template... not sure I have a solution for that one...

Answer (score 2):

Write to your compiler manufacturer and ask them why they don't optimise for this case. Then, hopefully, they'll add constant string concatenation to the list of optimisations and everyone's code will go faster without having to do anything!

That would be my favourite solution.

Comment: Agreed.  But I was hoping for a solution sometime prior to my retirement. =)

Comment: How did you get to 26.6K reputation with answers like this? (that's rhetorical; your answer is the only one with upvotes...)

Comment: Indeed, I would expect a decent compiler with, say, libstdc++'s string first inline the trivial `operator+=(p)`, which just calls `append(p)`. Then it should inline that trivial function, which (a debug check aside) just calls `append(p, traits::length(p))`. Then it should inline `traits::length(p)`, which is a trivial wrapper around `strlen(p)` (actually `__builtin_strlen`, but whatever). And since `p` is a known constant after all this inlining, the compiler should replace that with the known result. But apparently MSVC isn't smart enough for that.

Comment: sometimes I write constructive answers that take me time to think out, test and write... and other times I just go with the flippant ones. Guess which gets me more upvotes :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about just:

```
const std::string const_string("const string");
std::string s;
s += initial_string;
s += const_string;
s += terminating_string;
```

Comment: Performs reasonably well (but not as well as const/sizeof), and I don't want to pre-declare all my constant strings.  Also `s += std::string( "const string" )` is going the wrong way performance-wise (kind of surprised that that couldn't be optimized better by the compiler, MSVC2012)...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the MSVC compiler. Would reserving a sufficiently large buffer improve the performance?

Something along these lines

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string fast_concat(string s, const string& terminating_string) {

  static const string const_string("const string");

  s.reserve(s.size() + const_string.size() + terminating_string.size());

  s.append(const_string);

  s.append(terminating_string);

  return s;
}

int main() {

  cout << fast_concat("initial_string, ", ", terminating string") << endl;

}
```

(I am hoping for moves when capturing the first argument by value and also when returning the result.)

Comment: Pre-reserving string storage does in fact improve performance when assembling a series of known-length strings, but it's a different improvement than the constant concatenation itself (I was specifically trying to remove an unnecessary `strlen`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can get `strlen` in compile time with a template

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

template <size_t N>
void concat_char_array(string& s, const char (&array)[N]) {

    s.append(array, N-1);
}

string fast_concat(string s, const string& terminating_string) {

  concat_char_array(s, "const string");

  s.append(terminating_string);

  return s;
}

int main() {

  cout << fast_concat("initial string, ", ", terminating string") << endl;

}
```

It should be just as fast as it is with macros.